# Upgrading my HTC G1 to SDK 2.2

Tags: 2.2-froyo

I am trying to upgrade my HTC G1 to OS 2.2 (I have a developer device bought way back when it was released)

I have been trying the steps provided here - http://code.google.com/p/android-roms/wiki/SPL but for some reason the phone won't boot up after following all the steps. I have tried twice and restored my device to 1.5. But would really like to upgrade to 2.2

Any ideas please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rooting your G1 and putting something like [Cyanogenmod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=HTC_Dream) on your phone?  CM6 is currently in Release Candidate status and supports 2.2.  However, you won't get all the features of 2.1+ because the G1 simply cannot do some of them (i.e. LiveWallpapers).

Comment: The rest of us would love to know what worked for you, lostInTransit